# How do I fetch items from a specific view(s) of a Sharepoint list in SPFX?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnpjs

I'm trying to fetch items from a specific view of a Sharepoint list in SPFX using @pnp/sp library but I'm unable to do so. I'm able to fetch the view properties and fields of the list. I didn't find anything as such to fetch the items of that view. How will I be able to acheive the same and also my list contains Lookup columns as well.

Comment: There is another similar thread here (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264455/how-get-sharepoint-list-items-by-views-in-spfx)

Answer (score 0):

Sample test code for your reference.

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyDoc2').views.getByTitle("All Documents").get().then((view: any) => {
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyDoc2').getItemsByCAMLQuery({
        ViewXml: `<View><Query>`+view.ViewQuery+`</Query></View>`
      }).then((items: any) => {
        console.log(items);
      });
    })
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. The list has Lookup fields as well so, how do I expand those fields using this method getItemsByCAMLQuery?

Comment: If the lookup filed displays in your view, you could get the lookup item id as items[i].TestLookupId, TestLookup is the lookup field.